# Best classifier for data with text among features

Tags: classification, prediction

What is the best classifier when we have data a train set within a text among features.

Here is the situation:

I have a train set X (6 features) and a label 2 of the features is a text. Than I need to construct a model that can predict labels of the test set. Note that there is more than 5000 possible label.

I would say that `KNN` will be the best solution where I can measure the similarity between the text feature of the train set and its correspondent in the test set. But that wouldn't be possible because of the large size of data (millions).

Comment: You might want to avoid using the word 'best', as it implies optimal which is unlikely to be achieved in your case (this word has very specific meaning in statistics, usually optimal under a squared error loss function).  Furthermore you might want to give an example of a few observations including features and the label; in particular I find "label 2 of the features is a text"  what does this mean, and what is 'text"?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to vectorise the text features (eg. using TF-IDF), use a matrix factorisation technique (eg. SVD) to reduce the dimensinality to a manageable size (say 200 features), and use these features as predictors for your model.

Also you should probably sample your dataset for your training set, you shouldn't need millions of rows to train your model, 10,000 - 100,000 should be more appropriate.